# No back button in virtual device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am starting into Android I managed to start a simple app I made in a virtual device. Problem: There is no back button in the device.
I am using eclipse ADT and the device says on top: emulator64-arm. Not sure what other information are needed to provide to help me

Comment: Try the Esc key in your keyboard and see if it works.

Comment: @LucasT.:Yes! with ESC it went back!

Comment: This is a perfectly appropriate development tool question, and by no means a one-time issue unique to the poster.

Answer (score 1):

Your emulator image is emulating a device with a hardware BACK button, and so it does not show up in a navigation bar in the device itself. As was noted in the comments, <kbd>Esc</kbd> on your desktop OS will map to BACK in the emulator.

If you want to change your emulator to not have hardware BACK buttons, in `~/.android/avd/.../config.ini` (where `...` is the name of the AVD), set `hw.mainKeys=no`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by edit your AVD by checking "Display a skin with hardware control". after restart your avd back button should show in your virtual device.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio, you need to set skin on emulator.
Here's how you do it.

1. Click on Device Manager -> Create Virtual Device
2. Choose a device (e.g Pixel 3) and look at right side and click on "Clone Deice".
3. Scroll down and choose skin. Default is no skin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this from the command line and it will simulate a back button push in your emulator.

```
adb shell input keyevent 4
```